# How to make matplotlib work in ipython console connecting to a remote ipython kernel

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, ipython

I started a ipython kernel on a Ubuntu machine and would like to connect it from a (qt)console from windows to run some matplotlib plotting code, it work when I set the remote kernel to use the inline backend, however how I can make it work with a qt backend? i.e. I need a separated window popup for plot on my windows side instead of a inline (small) plot with the console? thanks

Comment: That's hard - you need something like X over SSH to show windows from a remote machine. I don't know how to do that from a Windows machine, though it's probably possible somehow, but I suspect it's not worth the trouble of setting it up. If you use the notebook, you can use the matplotlib nbagg backend to have pannable/zoomable plots in HTML.